# Creating a function to get user location in React Native logging but not returning the updated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm writing the below function that should get the user's current location and then update the predefined location properties:

```
export const getCurrentLocation = () => {
  const location = {
    userLat: '5',
    userLng: ''
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      //getting the Longitude from the location json
      const currentLongitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);

      //getting the Latitude from the location json
      const currentLatitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);

      location.userLat = currentLatitude;

      console.log('lat: ', location.userLat);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.warn(error);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: false,
      timeout: 30000,
      maximumAge: 1000
    },
  );
  return (
    location
  );
}
```

I equated `location.userLat` to `currentLatitude` and this logs correctly on the console, however when the function is done running, the produced `userLat` is still its initial value of `5`. I alternatively tried using `useState` hooks to update the value but got the error of `invalid hook calls`. Any tips or suggestions on how to make it reflect the `currentLatitude` value will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it seems that `getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous function. Note that this doesn't mean it's declared `async` or that it returns a Promise object that can be `await`-ed on.

You can convert your `getCurrentLocation` function to an `async` function and wrap the `getCurrentPosition` call in a Promise.

```
const getCurrentPosition = (options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options))
  };
};

export const getCurrentLocation = async (options) => {
  const location = {
    userLat: '5',
    userLng: ''
  };

  try {
    const position = await getCurrentPosition(options);

    //getting the Longitude from the location json
    const currentLongitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);

    //getting the Latitude from the location json
    const currentLatitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);

    location.userLat = currentLatitude;
    location.userLng = currentLongitude;

    console.log('lat: ', location.userLat);
  } catch(error) {
    console.warn(error);
  }

  return location;
}
```

Consuming code:

```
const options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: 30000,
  maximumAge: 1000,
};

const { userLat, userLng } = await getCurrentLocation(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Drew stated getting the location is happening asynchronously, so that `retun` is happening before the `console log`. Another way of talking this is to transform your function to a `hook`, so you will be able to use `useState`. Like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export const useGgetCurrentLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    userLat: "",
    userLng: "",
  });
  const [fetchingLocation, setFetchingLocation] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        setLocation({ userLat: position.coords.latitude, userLng: position.coords.longitude });
        setFetchingLocation(false);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.warn(error);
        setError("Something went wrong!");
        setFetchingLocation(false);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return { location, fetchingLocation, error };
};
```

And you would use it as below. First you would get `fetchingLocation` containing `true`, then it becomes `false`, and whether the location is successful or not, you would get `error` containing a message or `location` containing the actual latitude and longitude.

```
const { location, fetchingLocation, error } = useGgetCurrentLocation();
```

Comment: If you create a hook for this you might want to call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` from a `useEffect` hook (*with appropriate dependency array*) so it's not called each time the component renders. If I'm not mistaken this looks like it may actually cause a render loop to occur since it unconditionally updates React state.

Comment: You are totally right @DrewReese. I kind of missed that. Edited my answer. Thanks!